# Joining 3 tables together

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve data from these 3 tables

```
users
+----------+-----------+
| username | last_name |
+----------+-----------+
| name     | last name |
+----------+-----------+
messages
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+
| id | to_user | from_user | message | read | sent                |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+
| 12 |      12 |        10 | 1       |    0 | 2012-01-10 17:06:14 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+
all_messages
+----+--------+--------+
| id | user_1 | user_2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |     10 |     12 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I need to select all this data but only where `user_1` is equal to `random number`
and `user_2` is equal to `from_user` and `user_2` is equal to `users`.`id` now if there would only be 2 tables i have no problem selecting data i need but i don't know how to join table 3 which is `users` there is mine current query without `users` table included:

```
SELECT `all_messages`.`user_1`, `messages`.*
FROM `all_messages`
JOIN `messages` 
ON (`all_messages`.`user_2` = `messages`.`from_user`) 
WHERE `all_messages`.`user_1` = '12'
ORDER BY `messages`.`id` DESC LIMIT 2
```

**EDIT** Thank you for your answers it worked perfectly,

But what if i need to get only last record from `messages` because now it gets all records where `all_messages.user_2 = messages.from_user` and i need to get only one last `newest` record

Comment: do you have primary column in users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just add another "join" to your query with the third table:

```
SELECT `all_messages`.`user_1`, `messages`.*
FROM `all_messages`
JOIN `messages` 
ON (`all_messages`.`user_2` = `messages`.`from_user`) 
JOIN  `users`
ON (`users`.`id` = `all_messages`.`user_2`)
WHERE `all_messages`.`user_1` = '12'
ORDER BY `messages`.`id` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a new join, like this:

```
SELECT `all_messages`.`user_1`, `messages`.*
FROM `all_messages`
JOIN `messages` ON (`all_messages`.`user_2` = `messages`.`from_user`) 
JOIN users      ON (...write your condition here...)
WHERE `all_messages`.`user_1` = '12'
ORDER BY `messages`.`id` DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    users.username,users.last_name,messages.* 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM all_messages WHERE user_1=12) all_msgs
    INNER JOIN users ON messages.id = users.id
    INNER JOIN messages ON all_msgs.user_2 = messages.from_user
ORDER BY
    messages.id DESC LIMIT 2
;
```